# xcode ui testing Recoding fails to generate code

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode-ui-testing, xcode12.5

I created a new iOS SwiftUI app and added following ContenView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Button("Press Me", action: {
                return print("button pressed")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add an UI Test, where I check if the button is pressed.

What ever I do, after I press the recording button in the test no code is generated within the test function.

Every example have no issue at this point.

The record button is not greyed out an working.

Any Ideas what I have missed?

Comment: `return` statements don't belong inside the `action` of a `Button` remove that and your should see the `"button pressed"` statement in the console

Comment: Try attaching an accessibility identifier to element(s) of your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in Xcode 12.5.1, code generation works again ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UI test recording is not working in Xcode 12.5, try to install 12.4. it still works there.